# Most efficient way to write data to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop HDFS. I am trying to learn how to write data read from local file to hadoop HDFS . I want to know how to write in an efficient way. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
hadoop fs -put localpath hdfspath
```

**Example**

```
hadoop fs -put /user/sample.txt /sample.txt
```

You can google it to find more hdfs commands. Refer [here](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-commandline-manage-files-hdfs/)

Comment: Thank you Kumar. I am trying to write data to hdfs using Java API. Could you please help me with that. The team uses hadoop 2.0.0, HBase-0.92.1, Zookeeper -3.4.3